# R implementation of ECB AES-128 not compatible?

Tags: r, hash, aes

Im super new to encryption and so I tried to recreate a simple ECB AES-128 encryption as displayed with this online tool:
https://www.devglan.com/online-tools/aes-encryption-decryption

However, when trying to encrypt the plaintext:

"parameter1=1&parameter2=2&par3=3"

using the key:

"1234567890123456"

im getting different results from the digest R implementation and the abovementioned site.
Namely R gives me the hex result:

"00 63 2a 41 0a 39 0a ab b7 b9 80 b8 f1 4b 07 d9 a7 20 94 d6 b0 5b 57 17 67 68 36 a2 70 ca a2 8f"

while the online tool gives me:

"00 63 2A 41 0A 39 0A AB B7 B9 80 B8 F1 4B 07 D9 1B 09 5D 83 76 9F 6B 47 7E 51 FA D9 99 56 CE 2C B7 5A 26 54 C9 F3 6F EC 36 EF B5 D6 D2 1D 2C 0B"

Whats interesting is that the first 16 bytes are identical, but afterwards it differs.

Here is the code:

```
Test_String <- paste("parameter1=1", "parameter2=2", "par3=3", sep = "&")

Passphrase <- charToRaw("1234567890123456")

ECB_AES <- AES(key = Passphrase , mode = "ECB")

(Encrypted_Test_String <- ECB_AES$encrypt(Test_String))
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce the content of the posted ciphertext of the online tool. The ciphertext has a length of 48 bytes, but the first 32 bytes correspond to the ciphertext of the R code. The different length is probably caused by the fact that the R code does not pad, while the online tool does (PKCS7). Check the ciphertext of the online tool again.

Comment: @Topaco I'm gonna look into that, thank you very much! At least that might be a starting point. Btw, where did you find which padding algorithm they use?

Comment: By comparing with [this](https://gchq.github.io/CyberChef/#recipe=AES_Encrypt(%7B'option':'UTF8','string':'1234567890123456'%7D,%7B'option':'Hex','string':''%7D,'ECB','Raw','Hex',%7B'option':'Hex','string':''%7D)&input=cGFyYW1ldGVyMT0xJnBhcmFtZXRlcjI9MiZwYXIzPTM) online tool that uses PKCS7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATE:** I've implemented padding support to `digest::AES()` by adding a `padding` paramter. It's off by default for backwards compatibility so you need to add `padding=TRUE` to your AES() calls. It's now on CRAN in version 0.6.32.

---

**If using an older version of {digest} without padding support (before 2023-06-26):**

To expand on the answer by @PaulEagle , here is a function that takes a plaintext string and converts it to a raw vector with padding:

```
pad <- function(plaintext) {
  block_length <- 16
  bytes_to_pad <- block_length - (nchar(plaintext) %% block_length)
  padded_raw <- c(charToRaw(plaintext), rep(as.raw(bytes_to_pad), times = bytes_to_pad))
  padded_raw
}
```

The original function provided in Paul's answer did not work for me, so I had to modify it a little bit. As an example:

```
test <- "parameter1=1&parameter2=2&parameter3=3&par4=4"
pad(test)
```

Produces

```
70 61 72 61 6d 65 74 65 72 31 3d 31 26 70 61 72 61 6d 65 74 65 72 32 3d 32 26 70 61 72 61 6d 65 74 65 72 33 3d 33 26 70 61 72 34 3d 34 03 03 03
```

Also note that if you're using the "CBC" or "CTR" modes of AES, then the {openssl} package should work because it automatically handles padding, but it doesn't have a "ECB" mode.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case anyone needs this again, here is the solution I came up with, thanks to @Topaco 's hint.

The issue is indeed that, by default, digest::AES() does not pad the raw converted plain text.

The online tool referenced in my inital post, and most online tools for that matter, do use PKCS7 which fills the gap to the block length (16 bytes) with the byte representation of the gap length, or by 16 if the block length is exactly aligned.

Example: The plain text "parameter1=1&parameter2=2&parameter3=3&par4=4" raw converted

```
Test_String <- "parameter1=1&parameter2=2&parameter3=3&par4=4"
Raw_Test_String <- charToRaw(Test_String)
```

is of length 45 (70 61 72 61 6d 65 74 65 72 31 3d 31 26 70 61 72 61 6d 65 74 65 72 32 3d 32 26 70 61 72 61 6d 65 74 65 72 33 3d 33 26
70 61 72 34 3d 34) so the gap to block length 16 (16 * 3 = 48) is 3.
Therefore the string has to be padded by 3 3's in byte representation (03).
charToRaw does not work here so we need to use as.raw(3) to get the desired byte representation.

```
Raw_Padded_String <- c(Raw_Test_String, c(as.raw(3),as.raw(3),as.raw(3)))
```

which then produces the same output as the online tool if decrypted:

```
Passphrase <- charToRaw("1234567890123456")
ECB_AES <- AES(key = Passphrase , mode = "ECB")
(Encrypted_Test_String <- ECB_AES$encrypt(Raw_Padded_String))
```

Since there is no function to do this for a repeated process with whatever string length that I could find, here is one in case someone needs it:

```
PKCS7 <- function(Raw_Text, block_length = 16){
  
  bytes_to_padd <- (ceiling((length(Raw_Text) / block_length)) - (nchar(Raw_Text) / block_length)) * block_length
  
  if(bytes_to_padd == 0) bytes_to_padd <- 16
  
  Padded_Raw_Text <- c(Raw_Text, rep(as.raw(bytes_to_padd), times = bytes_to_padd))
  return(Padded_Raw_Text)
  
}
```

I'm sure this isnt ideal, but it works for me.

Comment: This is a great answer, although the `PKCS7` function provided here doesn't quite work right (the text isn't converted to raw). I fixed that and also simplified the function a little bit in my own answer.

Answer (score 0):

In your online tool, the available keysizes are 128, 196 and 256 bit.

If you take a look at your `ECB_AES`, it tells you that your key size in `R` is 16

```
> ECB_AES
AES cipher object; mode ECB key size 16
```

Comment: Its 16 bytes long (31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 30 31 32 33 34 35 36) so 128 bit or am i wrong?